# Methods containing bang doesn't work in REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I am running **Scala 2.9.2 REPL** and if I copy&paste following method:

```
  def isPrime(num: Int): Boolean = {
    val ceiling = math.sqrt(num.toDouble).toInt
    (2 to ceiling) forall (x => num % x != 0)
  }
```

..from the file with a source code (where it works well) to the Interactive Interpreter. I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: != 0): event not found
   at jline.console.ConsoleReader.expandEvents(ConsoleReader.java:426) 
   ...
```

The problem is the `!` character (methods without exclamation mark works well).

Is there any way to make the method work in the REPL?

Comment: This works well for me in Scala 2.9.2 and 2.10.1 on Ubuntu. What system are you running it on?

Comment: strange, Fedora 17 (32 bit PAE), Oracle Java 7 (but it is the same on OpenJDK and Oracle Java 6)

Comment: Perhaps jLine is reading a config file (some `.*rc` file) that enables a shell-like history function?

Comment: Looks like a bug https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6143 (unfortunately (for me) they closed it as NOT A BUG) :/

Comment: Deleted my incorrect answer--you should add your own answer with how you got around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed this instance:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7650

But the paulp fix isn't backward compatible.

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._, definitions._ also imported    **
** Try  :help, :vals, power.<tab>           **

scala> $r.r.in.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.JLineReader].consoleReader.setExpandEvents(false)

scala> 1 != 2
res1: Boolean = true
```

as opposed to crashing on 2.11:

```
scala> 1 != 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: != 2: event not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for Scala 2.9.2 (`setExpandEvents()` method is missing on `JLineConsoleReader` class in that version) Also I had to replace `$r.r.in...` with `$r.repl.in...` to make it work. I accept this answer, because it solves the issue for newer versions of Scala, where the API is in place.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to overcome this issue with the original installation, but installing new version of Scala helped. Perhaps, it is issue of Fedora 17 rpm Scala package.

- [Related bug](http://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6143)
- [rpm package with "broken" REPL](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20114153/dir/fedora_17/com/scala-2.9.2-4.fc17.noarch.rpm.html)